# Unable to find bin floder for MInGW

Tags: c, mingw

I want to download gcc compiler for vs code. I installed minGW .exe file from official site for 64 bit architecture.
sites I took help from [VS code instruction for minGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) [minGW official site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download)

Now I can't see any in Bin folder in **C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0**

I installed multiple time (deleted again everytime) and with another architecture too, but it's the same problem evrytime.

Comment: The bin folder is inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGW\mingw-w64.` I don't think a folder called `i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0` exists in MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

A standalone version can of a more recent GCC with MinGW-w64 can be downloaded from https://winlibs.com/, it doesn't require any installation, just extract the downloaded archive.

If you still have issues you can also try uninstalling your older version.